# How to exit gracefully with ExecutorService and Future

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I've three threads Producer, Processor, Consumer and all have blocking queues to share data between them. I wanted to join these threads and I'm using future for that so the code looks like -

```
public class Test {


    private static class Producer implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        private Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = checkNotNull(queue);
        }

        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                int i = 0;
                while (++i < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    addEntry(i);
                }
            } finally {
                addEntry(-1);
            }
        }

        private void addEntry(int i) {
            try {
                queue.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Processor implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<Integer> readQueue;
        private final BlockingQueue<Integer> writeQueue;

        private Processor(BlockingQueue<Integer> readQueue, BlockingQueue<Integer> writeQueue) {
            this.readQueue = checkNotNull(readQueue);
            this.writeQueue = checkNotNull(writeQueue);
        }

        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                int i = readQueue.take();
                while (i != -1) {
                    writeQueue.put(i);
                    i = readQueue.take();
                    if(i==1000){
                        throw new NullPointerException();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                addEntry(-1);
            }
        }

        private void addEntry(int i) {
            try {
                writeQueue.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        private Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = checkNotNull(queue);
        }

        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                int i = queue.take();
                while (i != -1) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    i = queue.take();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> readQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
        BlockingQueue<Integer> writeQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        Runnable[] runnables = new Runnable[]{new Producer(readQueue), new Processor(readQueue, writeQueue), new Consumer(writeQueue)};
        List<Future<?>> futures = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (Runnable runnable : runnables) {
            futures.add(executorService.submit(runnable));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch( ExecutionException e){
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }finally{
                future.cancel(true);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done..");
    }
}
```

Now if Futute#get() throws exception (NPE in Processor) I would like to stop all threads (Producer, Processor, Consumer) and exit gracefully.

How I can achive that?

Comment: You can `shutdown()` the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: `executorService.shutdownNow();` will interrupt all running threads. How *graceful* do you need?

Comment: I'm calling shutdown() and shutdownnow() - check the main method code.. Do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a thread to exit. You can only signal it and code the thread to exit when it receives the signal. You can use thread interruption as a way to signal threads to exit. If you want executing threads to exit when you call `executorService.shutdownNow()`, then the thread should exit when it is interrupted.

For example, in your `Consumer`:

```
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            int i = queue.take();
            while (i != -1) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i = queue.take();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

When the thread is interrupted, it just calls `interrupt()` on itself again. This doesn't accomplish anything. The `run` method should return when it receives an `InterruptedException`:

```
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            int i = queue.take();
            while (i != -1) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i = queue.take();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Consumer interrupted");
            return;
        }
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter in Processor - I'm throwing NPE and catching InterruptedException- so ideally that thread should exit. I'm worried about other two threads - they should exit.